# Parsing massive file with with Grep, Awk, Etc

Tags: linux, parsing, awk, active-directory, grep

I am working on a project for work and I am seeking your input.
I have to parse a massive CSV file (1.5 Gigs) containing everything from another companies Active Directory structure. One of the things that I have to do from the data is find all lines containing a 3 letter prefix with a period Ex. "ABC."

I am not asking for how you use basic Linux or Windows command line tools, but rather if anyone is partial to one tool over another when dealing with massive csv files in parsing data.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: 1.5Gig is not that huge these days....

Comment: Sure, for most data I agree but a 1.5 GB CSV file is massive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is unsorted then just use

```
grep '^ABC\.' file
```

It is is sorted then this might be more efficient:

```
awk '/^ABC\./{print; f=1; next} f{exit}' file
```

Comment: Or, to avoid reading the whole sorted file if the prefix never matches, `awk '/^ABC\./ $0>"ABC."{exit}'`

Comment: @rici good point but I wonder if that'd be less efficient when `ABC.` IS present since you're now doing a string comparison on every preceding line instead of a numeric test on 1/0?

Comment: Interpreter overhead probably means that the two tests are similar.

Answer (score 1):

actually, grep, awk etc. are pretty much optimized for performance so I don't think there's a need to doubt their efficiency. what you might want to consider is to use [GNU parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) to make use of a multi-core CPU for running the same command on parts of the input data in parallel. btw 1.5G is not *that* big :)

also, don't rely on people's opinions over the ol' good profiling.

Answer (score 1):

[Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/) (mlr) is the swiss army knife to parse and manage CSV/TSV/JSON data in any possible ways.

See https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html

With only the basics you might be able to do almost any kind of analysis very quickly with a small learning curve given the large set of built-in functions (aka [verbs](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-verbs.html)).
If it's not enough, you can go much further with a [DSL](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-dsl.html) which will be a bit slower given the interpreted language.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with grep, depending on what the other CSV entries look like and where in the line you expect to find your three-letter prefix.

I might use awk for this, but I'd probably use perl just because it's what I've used most recently for text processing.

Things get more complicated if the CSV entries might be in quotes, might contain commas and be in quotes, or might contain escaped quotation marks.  But if all those things happen in columns to the right of where you expect to find your prefixes, you can ignore them.